# How to delete unwanted character between key and value in JSON?

Tags: json, regex, go

I have JSON like this: `{"key1": "value1", \n \n "key2": "value2\nwithnewline"}`

I want:

1. remove \n \n
2. keep value2\nwithnewline.

So I will have a valid JSON.

What I tried: regrex but failed figure out how to specify outside of key and value.

and this:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"key1": "value1", \n \n "key2": "value2\nwithnewline"}`
    var cleaned bytes.Buffer
    quoteCount := 0

    for i := 0; i < len(jsonStr); i++ {
        if jsonStr[i] == '"' {
            quoteCount++
        }

        if quoteCount%2 == 0 && jsonStr[i] != '\n' {
            cleaned.WriteByte(jsonStr[i])
        } else if quoteCount%2 == 1 {
            cleaned.WriteByte(jsonStr[i])
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(cleaned.String())
}
```

Link to Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/zvNSCuE4SjQ

This does not work because it can `\n` is actually `\` `n`

Comment: It would be better if you used a JSON parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the parameters of your question, you could replace all \n\n using `strings.ReplaceAll`:

`cleaned := strings.ReplaceAll(input, "\\n \\n ", "")`

If you want to continue using your current strategy, there's a few issues. One of them is that you're always writing to the string, regardless of your condition: `cleaned.WriteByte(jsonStr[i])` happens in your if and else cases.

Answer (score -1):

you can split and join

package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
)

```
func main() {
    jsonStr := `{"key1": "value1", \n \n "key2": "value2\nwithnewline"}`
    split := strings.Split(jsonStr, "\\n \\n")
    cleaned := strings.Join(split, " ")
    fmt.Println(cleaned)
}
```

Comment: This yields the same result as `strings.Replace` but is harder to read and uses twice as much memory.